# + Character in permalink

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I'm currently working on a new website that I need to migrate from an old CMS to WordPress. The old system had some URL values with ID's in it:

```
http://www.domain.ltd/page+1234.
```

When I place this url in WordPress, the URL gets a `301` redirect to the same URL with the value: `%2B`. Can someone help me out to get rid of the redirect and just show the URL with the `+`?

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, pleace write it as an answer and accept it, so it may help others to see that this question was solved, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Per the OP, here is their answer which I separated from the question:

> I have found a solution for it myself, I've used the [Custom Permalinks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) and edited how the special characters are saved in the database. For the people who want to use this, change:

```
add_post_meta( $id, 'custom_permalink', str_replace('%2F', '/',
urlencode(ltrim(stripcslashes($_REQUEST['custom_permalink']),"/"))) );
```

**to**

```
add_post_meta( $id, 'custom_permalink', str_replace(array('%2F','%2B'),
array('/','+'),
urlencode(ltrim(stripcslashes($_REQUEST['custom_permalink']),"/"))) );
```

Comment: @TimMalone Sure thing.